# Pointwise convergence in a Sturm-Liouvlle problem.

Tags: pointwise-convergence, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Let's consider a Sturm-Louiville problem in $[0,1]$. For me it's clear that a Fourier series of eigenfunctions converges uniformely for any continously differentiable function $F$ with $F(0)=F(1)=0$ and second derivative piecewise continous. Equivalentily, for the Green's Function $G(s,t)$, there is a piecewise continous $f(t)$ such that $ F(s) = \int_0^1 G(s,t) f(t) dt$. Said that, I don't know in which conditions pointwise convergence can be garanteed. I can give for example $G(s,t)$ for a given $s$. It is continously differentiable execpt at $t=s$, where there is a jump discontinuity in the derivative. How can I prove pointwise convergence in a case like that? You can assume that the eigenvalues are all positive.

Comment: You should state your version of the SL equation and also specify which object you want to converge pointwise.

Comment: The most basic version, $-(p y')'+q y = l y $, for $y(0)=y(1)=0$, $p(t)$ positive and $q(t)$ non negative. I cannot specify the object because i'm precisely asking which conditions a function has to obbey to garantee pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Theorem from the first chapter of E. C. Titchmarsh's book on Eigenfunction Expansions:

**1.9 Theorem** Let $f(y)$ be integrable over $(a,b)$. Then if $a < x < b$ the Sturm-Liouville expansion behaves as regards convergence in the same way as an ordinary Fourier series. In particular, it converges to $\frac{1}{2}\{f(x+0)+f(x-0)\}$ if $f(x)$ if of bounded variation in the neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Does that mean that it converges pointwise where the function is differentiable or Hölder continous? More specifically, is there an analogue of the Dini test?

Comment: One converges at $y$ iff the other does. So you can apply whatever test you like.

Comment: @JoãoPedroBarbosaCoelho If this answers your question, then please select the checkmark to the left of my answer. You may optionally +1 the answer as well.